# Uninstalling Silverlight 4 beta on OS X

Tags: macos, uninstall, silverlight

I want to downgrade to SL3 on my Mac after accidently installing SL4 Beta.
I've tried the SL3 uninstall procedure:

```
rm -rf /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/Silverlight.plugin
rm -rf /Library/Receipts/Silverlight*.pkg
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Microsoft/Silverlight
```

But still get an error message when I try to install SL3 saying there is a newer version there.

Anyone got any input on how to do this ?

Answer (score 3):

The answer to my problem was to remove SL receipts:

```
sudo rm /private/var/db/receipts/com.microsoft.installSilverlightPlugin*
```

Thanks to this thread:

> http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/151634/338848.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting

```
com.microsoft.silverlight.plist
```

in

```
~/Library/Preferences/
```